# Intel Edison getting started with mini breakout board and Eclipse -- need getting started guide

Tags: eclipse, intel-edison

I have set up my Intel Eclipse mini breakout board using this getting started http://youtu.be/-JwOB6vvETw.  It is very good but only takes you to where you can talk to the Edison with Putty.  That works.  Then I used this guide https://software.intel.com/en-us/getting-started-for-c-c-plus-plus-eclipse-galileo-and-edison.  I installed Eclipse and tried to run the "Hello World" example.  I get an error "Error Starting Process" and details of "Launching Failed".

I turned to Google but I seem to be one of the first people to get this thing (Amazon delivered in under 24 hours).  I looked on YouTube but find that all the relevant clips show "Watched" as I have already watched them.

Of course I tried the Intel Getting Started site.  They say that their getting started guide is for their larger Arduino Breakout Board and that if you want a getting started guide for any other breakout board to look on the manufacturers site.  But Intel makes the mini breakout board so this is very frustrating.  I have confirmed that the Arduino Getting Started Guide does not work with the mini breakout board.

I need some guidance in just running any program into the Intel Edison Mini Breakout Board from Eclipse.

EDIT: WiFi WAP requires either a 5 or 13 character password.  All I had was a 104 bit key.  I set up a second router with a WPA password and now WiFi works.  I still don't know how to connect the mini breadboard to Eclipse.

EDIT2: Solved by following this guide
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/519930
and entering the WiFi address as the requested ip address.  I did not use the USB ip address nor did I try after previously having that fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Start-up guide will not work with the mini breakout board.  It only works with the Arduino* expansion board.  What works is a combination of the two guides in my initial question but you must get WiFi working first.

When you go through the "Getting Started for C/C++ (Eclipse) - Galileo & Edison" at one point it asks what the ip address is.  Use the WiFi IP Address.  I had initially used the USB IP address and that did not work.  That was the point where I posted this question.  After getting a side issue that I did not realize was connected and getting WiFi resolved, I used that WiFi IP address.  Now it works.  that said, it may be that you can get the USB IP address to work, it is just that I couldn't.  As my application needs the USB port for reading data, I didn't want it for program loading anyway.

In summary, get to the point where you can use Putty to get around Linux on the Edison with this tutorial http://goo.gl/BmRuco or this video http://youtu.be/-JwOB6vvETw

Then get Eclipse and C running using this getting started guide http://goo.gl/L1y3tq

But get WiFi working first.  Use WPA and not WAP in your router if you have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [full IOT Dev kit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/downloads), it comes with few samples that you can try running.

IOT Dev Kit should work on all versions of Edison or Galileo.

For a [start-up guide please see this link](http://intel.com/Edison/getstarted), also referred in above IOT Dev kit page.

Comment: That getting started start-up guide does not work for the mini breakout board but this one does https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/519930  The IOT development kit does work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going through SCP instead.

- Make sure your edison is connected to wifi
- Compile your app, then go to the debug or release folder (depending on what build configuration you're running)
- Use secure copy (scp, should be an option in PuTTy) to copy the executable to your edison, to the `/home/root` folder

After that, I was able to run my app.

Comment: WiFi is another issue.  It discovers my router fine first try but asks for a 5 or 13 bit password and my password is 26 bits.  I found that strange.  Are you saying that Eclipse will not worn with the mini breakout board?

Comment: Or are you saying that you use Eclipse to compile but scp to get the executable to the edison instead of using the Eclipse run function?

Comment: @AllenEdwards I use Eclipse to compile and then SCP to move it over and run. I didn't have a problem connecting to my WPA2 secured router with my standard password (which is 8 characters). Are you running the latest firmware?

Comment: I have connected now with a WPA password on a second router.  I was using a WAP key of 104 bits and no password.  Edison can't handle it as apparently some Windows systems can't either.

Comment: I have it working.  I used this guide https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/519930 and used the ip address for the wifi when it asked for an ip address.  The secret seemed to be to 1) Get the wifi working and 2) use the wifi ip address instead of the serial port address although I did not try the serial port after getting it to work.  My example file is on the Edison and it runs.  I can print "Hello World" to my remote terminal using putty.  This is very cool.

Comment: Your original question didn't ask anything about WiFi. If your answer is different than any of the others provided, post it as such, and mark accepted. Editing to the title to include "solved" isn't the SO way to do that.

Comment: What I wanted to do was to give 1/2 credit to each of the replies but I also wanted an answer that would help those that came later.  As this is a very new product with lots of people having trouble, I thought that important.  Your solution works for sure but interfacing directly with Eclipse without having to use SCP seems better. You also correctly identified the WiFi problem and that was a great help.  Thank you so much for your help.